# JTable Keep Group of Rows always first when sorting ASC or DESC

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowsorter

I Have a JTable I am using to show some data, the data consists basically of (Key,Value) pairs.

I enable sorting of the Table by the Key Column.

But I need a group of keys to always be at the top no matter if it is sorted ascending or descending.

Exameple :

**Unsorted**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Key A | Value A |
| Key C | Value C |
| Key B | Value B |
| Key 1 | Value 1 |
| Key 3 | Value 3 |
| Key 2 | Value 2 |
| Key 4 | Value 4 |

**Sorted ASC**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Key A | Value A |
| Key B | Value B |
| Key C | Value C |
| Key 1 | Value 1 |
| Key 2 | Value 2 |
| Key 3 | Value 3 |
| Key 4 | Value 4 |

**Sorted DESC**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Key C | Value C |
| Key B | Value B |
| Key A | Value A |
| Key 4 | Value 4 |
| Key 3 | Value 3 |
| Key 2 | Value 2 |
| Key 1 | Value 1 |

I created a rowsorter with a comparator and was able to get the Sorted ASC,

```
final TableRowSorter<CTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<CTableModel>((CTableModel) this.getModel());
sorter.setComparator(0, new CJTableComparator());
sorter.setSortable(1, false);
```

but the defaultrowsorter orders the desc by multiplying the row numbers by -1.

```
private int compare(int model1, int model2) {
...    
    if (sortOrder == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
        result *= -1;
    }
```

and seeing how the method is private I cannot override it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could handle this?

```
class CJTableComparator implements Comparator {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        CTableModel model = ((CTableModel)CJTable.this.getModel());

        String so1 = o1.toString();
        String so2 = o2.toString();

        boolean isHeader1 = model.isHeader(so1);
        boolean isHeader2 = model.isHeader(so2);


        if(isHeader1 == isHeader2){

        }else if(isHeader1){
            so1 = "0"+so1;
            so2 = "9"+so2;
        }else if(isHeader2){
            so1 = "9"+so1;
            so2 = "0"+so2;
        }

        return so1.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(so2.toString());
    }
}
```

Table Model

```
public class CTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private final HashMap<String, CTableModelRow> rowsbyId = new HashMap<String, CTableModelRow>();

    private final HashMap<String, CTableModelRow> rowsHeaders = new HashMap<String, CTableModelRow>();

    static Object[][] empty = {{}};

    private static final String[] DEFALT_COLUMNS = {"TAG", "VALUE", "PREV"};

    public CTableModel (){
        super(empty,DEFALT_COLUMNS);
        this.setRowCount(0);
    }

    public CTableModelRow getRowByNumber(int number){
        return rowsbyNumber.get(number);
    }

    public boolean isHeader(String key){
        return rowsHeaders.containsKey(key);
    }
}
```

END.

Comment: Don't rely on the inbuilt automatic (simplistic) row sorting, and instead define a custom `RowSorter`. **Edit:** *"I created a rowsorter.."* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table. Show your best attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the code of `CJTableComparator`. You need to change it so that it handles your specific sorting requirements. Without seeing the code, I can't help you. It might also be helpful to see the code for class `CTableModel`.